# cart price rule not applied for free shipping

Tags: magento-2.1.7, free-shipping

I need to apply free shipping for specific products with specific attribute.

for example products with attribute `condition` is equal to `true`.

I add the following conditions

```
if one of those condition is true
   if an item is found in cart with all of those conditions are true
      `condition` is `true`
      subtotals in cart is equal to or greater than 3000
   if substotal is 3000 for a subselection of items in cart matching all of these conditions:
      `condition` is `true`
```

I've enabled free shipping with `Minimum order quantity` equal to 3000. and rule is enabled until 31/12/2020

the result of that is free shipping is applied whenever subtotals in cart are equal to 3000

Comment: Your product attribute should be enable for promotion and then you can need to use condition product attribute condition and assign your custom attribute in condition.

Comment: @AmanAlam I cannot find such a setting in stores>attributes>product for that attribute

Comment: https://www.amanweb.in/stackexchange/promoconditionscr.jpg

Comment: Check above screen shot.

Comment: it's already enabled